# custom compile time error

Tags: java

I want to show a compile time error when i call a method.

Like i have a class "MyClass" in which there are two methods "methodA()" and "methodB()".
now i make a instance of "MyClass" . using this instance i can call both methods but i need to show an compile time error if i call "methodB()" before "methodA()";
strong text

```
class MyClasss
{
    public void methodA()
    {
        //do some thing
    }
    public void methodB()
    {
        //do some thing
    }
}
class MyRunningClasss
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        MyClass MC = new MyClass();

        // it will not give any compile time error.
        MC.methodA();
        MC.methodB();

        // but it have to  give compile time error.
        MC.methodB();
        MC.methodA();

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What compilation error are you referring to?

Comment: Hey dude Whey Cretae Class All method are Loaded into ur Object. you can call any method at any point of time. Whts is ur question.?

Comment: You can't do that. If users of your code must know that they must call `methodA` before calling `methodB`, use proper JavaDoc and throw an Exception in `methodB` in case `methodA` hasn't been called.

Comment: You can't do this at compile time.  The best you could do is to check a flag and throw an exception after an improper call to methodB

Comment: I have copied and run your code in eclipse .I can able to run your code without any errors and getting output with out any error. Which compiler you are using?

Comment: If method A is essential to the good operation of the object then could its functionality be included within the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are suggesting isn't easy.  You need to download the OpenJDK and change it.  It's a very large code base so I don't suggest you that.

Instead I suggest you add a runtime assertion check and unit test your code.  If you use maven or ant to run your tests as part of your build, these error will be detect at build time, even if it is your tests, not the compiler which detects the error.

What makes it particularly difficult for the compiler if you can do any number of things which  are difficult to determine at compile time.

e.g.

```
public static somethingA(int n) {
    // do something
    if(n == x)
       MC.methodA();
}

public static somethingB(int n) {
    // do something
    if(n == y)
        MC.methodB();
}

// is this a compile error or not
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    somethingB(i);
    somethingA(i);
}
```

There is many patterns where such a feature like this would be useful, it is just very hard to solve. e.g. making sure you Lock.unlock() after a Lock.lock(), but you can place these in different methods, or put conditions on them.

Comment: @vikrant You would also have to give this modified OpenJDK compiler to everyone who uses your code. The maintainability of this is enormously complicated and entirely unnecessary, not to mention you're basically throwing out a desire to stick to the Java language spec.

Comment: I agree that a compile-time check for this particular case is Turing-complete, but it's definitely not as hard to add additional checks to the JDK as you're implying it is -- OpenJDK's langtools.jar provides an API for the Java compiler that you can add checks to fairly straightforwardly.  The [error-prone project](https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/) 
does a lot of this, and we use it at Google.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code:

```
void callOne(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        methodA();
    else {
        methodB();
    }
}
void randomTry() {
    int x, y, z;
    x = 1 + Random.nextInt(1000);
    y = 1 + Random.nextInt(1000);
    z = 1 + Random.nextInt(1000);
    boolean b = (x*x*x + y*y*y == z*z*z);
    callone(b);
    callOne(!b);
}
```

The compiler would have to prove Fermat's last theorem in order to figure out that methodB is always called first.

Comment: Only for x, y and z up to 1000. This can be done by enumeration. It might increase compilation time, though.